# save() method on datasource does not fire querySave/postSave events

Tags: xpages

My save button uses SSJS with some logic. I want to save datasource, so I use

`document1.save();`

Script works, but querySave/postSave code is not executed.

Only workaround is to use simple action and divide button event to blocks for "execute script", "Save document (simple action)" and "execute script" (just to return "navigation" string).

Is it possible to save datasource in SSJS and fire qS/pS events?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

please try this SSJS code:

```
var dsName = "document1.DATASOURCE";
var app = facesContext.getApplication();
var ds = app.getVariableResolver().resolveVariable(facesContext, dsName);
ds.save( facesContext, true );
```

The variable dsName contains the name of your datasource followed by ".DATASOURCE". To use it f.e. with current document, you have to change to "currentDocument.DATASOURCE".

Hope this helps

Sven

Comment: @Sven: How can I control if save sucessfull? In my old code I used
var res=document1.save();
if (res) {
var url=view.getPageName()+"?action=openDocument&documentId="+document1.getNoteID();
context.redirectToPage(url);
}
So that if there are some problem I do not execute the redirect and I show error message

Comment: *var ret = ds.save( facesContext, true );* The save method has a return value: true if document was sucessfully saved, else false. This means that *querySave*-event did not returned false.

Answer (score 0):

Sven what is the difference between your code and currentDocument.save() is something else happening than querysave and postsave?

Comment: The difference is the type of object that will be used: If you save a document datasource, the method "save" of an object of type NotesXspDocument is called. If you do what if have described above, you will receive a object of type

Comment: com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData; this object has another method for saving. The first object type is like a backend NotesDocument, the second object is like the NotesUIDocument class.